# Получить корень n-ой степени

Tags: javascript

Как можно получить корень `n`-ой степени числа `x` в JavaScript?

Comment: ассоциация: https://stackoverflow.com/q/7308627/5812238

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Для частных случаев квадратного и кубического корня стоит использовать методы [`Math.sqrt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/sqrt) и [`Math.cbrt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cbrt) соответственно.

В общем случае корень `n`-ой степени числа `x` равен числу `x` в степени `1/n`, поэтому можно использовать метод [`Math.pow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/pow) или оператор [возведения в степень `**`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Arithmetic_Operators#%D0%92%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%B2_%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_(**)):

```
Math.pow(x, 1/n)
// или
x ** (1/n)
```

Например:

```js
console.log(Math.pow(81, 1/4));
console.log(81 ** (1/4));
```

---

Для отрицательных `x` предложенный способ вернёт `NaN`, что соответствует [определению корня](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%8C_(%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0)) (над действительными числами) для всех случаев кроме нечётных `n`. При отрицательных `x` и нечётных `n` можно написать проверку:

```
function nthRoot(x, n) {
    if (x < 0 && n % 2 === 1)
        return -Math.pow(-x, 1/n);
    else
        return Math.pow(x, 1/n)
}
```